# Is GO required before and after SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON/OFF

Tags: sql-server

Do I need GO before and after SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON/OFF?

I see a lot of samples, articles use this, but when I skip GO, the script works fine.

```
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [PropertyValue] ON
GO

-- Some script

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [PropertyValue] OFF
GO
```

I wonder if this is a good code conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to. The `GO` instructs eg. SQL Server Management Studio to execute the query as a separate command. Some clauses need this, and some don't.

For example, it's usually necessary to use `GO` to separate a `CREATE TABLE` clause from `INSERT`s into the same table.

**EDIT**: Seems this is no longer the case, as pointed out by Damien. `CREATE TABLE` can be followed by `INSERT` just fine, and the same applies to `DROP TABLE` and others. Always improving, eh? :) I've tried some other cases I remember, and it seems you no longer need to have a `CREATE PROCEDURE` as the last statement in a command either. Times change :)

`set identity_insert` doesn't need to be separated by `GO`. It's usually used as safe practice when you're autogenerating SQL code, because you're not necessarily aware of what's going on elsewhere (eg. you might have been creating the table in the previous clause, so to be sure, you put a `GO` before the identity insert). But it's not necessary, and will not yield you any specific benefit, if you use it in your hand written SQL that you execute as one batch.

Comment: I disagree with your chosen example. `create table T(ID int not null); insert into T(ID) values (1);` (all on a single line even) runs fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Hah, you're right. Times change. I remember it was impossible some time in the past (MS SQL 2000?), because it couldn't create a query plan, because the table didn't exist. It seems that this particular restriction is gone now. That is very useful, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I feel that GO is annoy. I wont need this.

Comment: do you know at what version of SQL Server separating create and insert into separate batches was made no longer necessary?

Answer (score 3):

`GO` is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the `sqlcmd` and `osql` utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.
SQL Server utilities interpret `GO` as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements entered since the last `GO`, or since the start of the ad hoc session or script if this is the first `GO`.
A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a `GO` command. However, the line can contain comments.
Users must follow the rules for batches. For example, any execution of a stored procedure after the first statement in a batch must include the `EXECUTE` keyword. The scope of local (user-defined) variables is limited to a batch, and cannot be referenced after a `GO` command.

Comment: When you copy and paste your response from official documentation, you should probably cite the source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx